# flutter FCM subscribe to a topic doesn't seem to work

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented FCM successfully. When i send a message from firebase console it comes to the emulator as well. But when i subscribe to a topic it doesn't filter any of the messages. It doesn't matter what i write to channel on firebase console, it comes anyway. Here is my main method.

Here is my main method:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
                            .subscribeToTopic('Herkes');
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
        create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(prefs.getString('theme')),
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

And my console logs after any message come:

> W/FirebaseMessaging( 4985): Notification Channel requested (Public2) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.
> W/FirebaseMessaging( 4985): Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.

Answer (score 0):

As in the official docs, you need to add the following metadata element in your AndroidManifest.xml within the application component:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

Comment: i added exactly like that also added the strings.xml and created the strings.xml in the location added the key there but again did not work. same results.